Flyway DB Script spelling mistake
I have a Flyway script that creates a new table to store reporting data to another table's data.
I made a mistake cutting & pasting from a Java object and as you can see in the script below, the "data_Item_id" should read "data_item_id". Now, in the database, the foreign key has been generated in lower case, so the only defect now appears to be in my Flyway script.
I can't just change the script, as this will cause flyway to throw errors as the script is no longer original, so can anyone suggest a way to correct this spelling mistake? Maybe a new script to drop the reference and re-create it?
create table if not exists reporting
(
    reporting_id      BIGSERIAL   unique not null,
    data_item_id      BIGINT references data_item (data_Item_id) not null,
    address           VARCHAR,
    name              VARCHAR,
    primary key (reporting_id)
);


SQL (incl. PostgreSQL) is normally case-insensitive - this shouldn't cause any problems unless you're using quoted-names.

You could also add a post-deploy script that renames things?

@Dai, that is an over simplification as the link you provides shows. The SQL standard says unquoted identifiers be up cased to all upper case, whereas Postgres does the opposite down cases to all lower case.  With double quotes you can get any mix, and can also include otherwise not permitted characters. The issue is different tools deal with this in different ways and you can end up with a mix of naming conventions.  Unless you control the entire process you should assume case sensitivity could be a thing.

@AdrianKlaver I have my copy of the $250 current ISO SQL spec right here; may I ask which page/section+subsection says "unquoted identifiers be up cased to all upper case"? (I'm asking sincerely, sorry if I sound antagonistic)(

My sources: 1) This Identifiers: he folding of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper case.  ... 2) SQL Identifier case:  SQL-92 specification section 5.2.13)

@AdrianKlaver SQL-92 is 30 years out of date. I'll look to see what's in the current spec, hang on

@AdrianKlaver Sorry for taking so long - in the current 2023 edition the rules about double-quoted names are buried under reams of Unicode technicalities... but from what I can tell, the spec indeed no-longer defines identifiers as being folded to uppercase: https://imgur.com/a/YAEgR3h


I don't see that, I see still references to folding to upper case. Also a lot seems to depend on Subclause 8.2 which is not shown. 2) This is the latest version and whether current versions of databases are fully compliant is doubtful. For Postgres see SQL Conformance. 3) I still stand by the assertion that assuming case insensitive  comparisons is going to get you into trouble.


you should be able to make the fix to the file then run flyway repair to update the checksum. That said, if flyway is complaining about this, it would be assumed that it has "successfully" run. If its only one database, the quick fix is to fix manually, then update the script and run repair.
Alternatively you can "fix forward", ie, add another script which, as you say, undoes the previous change and redoes it. If you have multiple environments and this migration has been deployed to some but not others, fixing forward is probably the right thing to do.
If you have Teams edition, you could create an undo script which backs out the create, run that undo on environments you have run it on, then either fix the script and run repair, or create a new migration, and use SkipExecute on the "bad one"
